# Вызов метода в программе из dll

Tags: c#, dll, loading

Скажите пожалуйста как вызвать метод с параметрами из dll? Ну вот например : в программе есть `public void writestr(string instring)` который просто присваивает `Label.content` принятую строку `instring`, так вот есть dll при инициализации которого нужно сделать что-то похожее на `writestr("hello from dll")`.

Comment: Какой код на C#, а какой нативный?

Comment: @Qwertiy В смысле ?))

Comment: Есть dll. На чём она написана? Есть программа - она на чём? Что из этого на C#?

Comment: Объясните мне, кто плюсует такие вопросы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Dll на C# так же как и сама программа, скажу даже больше, они в одном решении :D

Comment: Эм.. Тогда ты что-то странное спрашиваешь. Уточни вопрос. Тем более, на C# есть классы, а функций вне классов нет.

Comment: @Igor, я. Но я подумал, что вопрос о взаимодействии нативного кода с C#. Если бы понял правильно, то не стал бы.

Comment: @Qwertiy - я тоже сначала так подумал. Делегат ему надо подать в DLL/Assembly, а там его вызвать. Смущает только "при инициализации которого ", но спишем это на использование неправильного термина.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну я вот сделал ссылку из dll к моей программе, но там нету моего метода :( несмотря даже на то что метод у меня паблик

Comment: Метод не в dll, а в классе. Добавь в вопрос код.

Comment: @Qwertiy в смысле который в программе?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy Там нет "Вашего метода" - там есть Ваш класс. Label не висит в воздухе, он находится на форме. Label на какой форме должен изменить код из DLL?

Comment: @Igor ох, в общем всё заново, у меня есть основная программа в которой лежит метод `public void writestr` и обычный Label, ещё у меня есть dll которая подключается к программе во время старта(ну это не важно), так вот как из DLL вызвать `public void writestr` который лежит в основной программе?

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy - Label не может "лежать в программе", он лежит на форме или, как минимум, является членом класса. В общем, мы друг друга не поймем.

Comment: @Igor ну естественно Label лежит на форме, что за глупые вопросы :)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy - Извините, больше не буду. Привет.

Comment: @Igor хорошо так и быть, извиняю :D Привет